# workflow in node js example?

Tags: javascript, node.js, workflow

I have a project which has a few steps **example A->B->c->D** of each order .so I am trying to make this thing generic, or in other words I am trying to define my  `workflow` in `json` or in another format which has some steps so that I will minimal changes on codes if task or steps changes .

I found so many packages but they are all old or no one is using

http://joyent.github.io/node-workflow/

I also tried Netflix conductor with nodejs , but don't have much support.

https://github.com/Netflix/conductor

**could you please tell me any better option or any other package which save the state of my order and do the next steps if previous steps is done**

Comment: Well, it's off-topic here to ask for a package or library that will do what you want.  Instead, you should describe the ACTUAL problem and show the ACTUAL code and then we can offer some options for the best way to code it.  Please make this a question about your specific problem, not a generic and theoretical question.  We can help you so much better if we understand your actual problem and see your actual code.

Comment: For example, if you make each of your operations return a promise, it's fairly trivial to take an array of these tasks and run them in sequence one after the other.

Comment: see this example https://github.com/kusor/node-workflow-example

Comment: I have same use case but these packages are old not supported

Comment: It's as if you didn't read my first comment at all, particular the part "the ACTUAL problem and show the ACTUAL code" and "Please make this a question about your specific problem, not a generic and theoretical question."  Without this, your question is off-topic.  We don't answer questions here asking for a library to use.  We help you code solutions to some specific problem.

Comment: ok will remove / delete question ...!!